# jqgrid add dialog leave fields populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've a jqgrid and its add dialog. When I click on submit, data send correctly but insert fields are automatically cleaned. I want these fields to maintain their inserted content, and clean them only by recreating the add dialog. How can I manage that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as i understood you use jq dialog, you can use event

```
//Supply a callback function to handle the open event as an init option.
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) { 
   //
   //  HERE WRITE CODE OF FILLING DATA  INTO INPUT FIELD
   //
 }
});
//Bind to the open event by type: dialogopen.
$( ".selector" ).bind( "dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
   //
   //  HERE WRITE CODE OF FILLING DATA  INTO INPUT FIELD
   //

});
```